# Shell command doesn't work with # in it

Tags: macos, terminal

This is my shell command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo "#" > /file"
```

But it doensn't work but this does work:

```
sudo sh -c "echo "hi" > /file"
```

How can I fix this, because the # needs to be in it.

Comment: (Just a comment on "why?"; the given answers address "how to fix".) Double quotes don't nest. The `#` isn't part of the argument to the `-c` option; only `"echo "` is. The `#` simply marks the beginning of a comment on the line.

Comment: It needs to be in the file!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'hard' quotes for tricky characters:

```
sudo sh -c "echo '#' > /file"
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with the double quotes like it would if this was about a `$` character. `sudo sh -c 'echo "#" > /file'` would work as well. It's just that the original script line uses *the same quotes on both levels without escaping*, resulting in `sudo sh -c "echo "`, with the rest being a comment (possibly thanks to the `bash` option `interactive_comments`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use different quotes for just one character, you could also escape the hash character:

```
sudo sh -c "echo "\#" > /file"
```

Like in many scripting languages, shell commands interpret a hash character (`#`) as the beginning of a comment.

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

Comment: It doesn't work because all of the quotes are removed before the string is passed to `sudo` (and thence to `sh -c`). Essentially, it's executing the command `echo # > /file`, which is equivalent to just `echo`.